# Is List.removeIf() faster than a complex SQL query

Tags: sql, collections, spring-data-jpa

I know that a complex SQL query might be less memory overhead than handling list operations in Java, but is it faster?

I am using the JPA and SpringFramework to handle my database.

Here is how I am doing it:

```
TypedQuery<Precipitation> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("query_find_all_Precipitiation", Precipitation.class);
Predicate<Precipitation> precipPredicate = p -> p.getStation() != station;
List<Precipitation> results = query.getResultList();
results.removeIf(precipPredicate);
//Use results here
```

I'm doing it this way because I'm still rather new to doing database work, and I'm not strong in SQL, but I know how to manipulate java lists.

If memory is not an issue, is this a fast way to do it, or should I use a where in my query?

If I should use a where in my query, how do I do it using the Framework I am currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your complex sql query looks like a simple where clause to me. Assuming your "station" is a simple string attribute and you are using spring-data-jpa a solution could be as simple as that:

Define a Repository for your Precipitation Entities:

```
public interface PrecipitationRepository extends JpaRepository<Precipitation, Long> {

    List<Precipitation> findByStation(String station);
}
```

You can then inject and use the repository to find the Precipitations that have the required station:

```
List<Precipitation> results = precipitationRepository.findByStation("your station");
...further processing
```

For more information on how to define Spring Data Repositories look here [Spring Data JPA Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: Do you have any good sources for tutorials on how to build the Repository Interface up? The tutorials I found tell me to leave it completely empty, and I don't know what putting "List<Precipitation> findByStation(String station);" does for the interface.

Comment: Ok, I think I found one example of what you are trying to do. It seems what you are trying to do is include in the repository interface a method that the system will need to figure out how to fill. How does that differ from building a service that specifically outlines different methods of filling queries? This is how I've been doing it.

Comment: @Chthonic One Taken from [Spring Data JPA Homepage](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/)  Implementing a data access layer of an application has been cumbersome for quite a while. Too much boilerplate code has to be written to execute simple queries as well as perform pagination, and auditing. Spring Data JPA aims to significantly improve the implementation of data access layers by reducing the effort to the amount that’s actually needed. As a developer you write your repository interfaces, including custom finder methods, and Spring will provide the implementation automatically.

Comment: This is becoming obvious now that I am trying to write unit tests for it. I do greatly appreciate your help. One last thing, one of the advantages that people keep hammering me about with direct SQL is the ability to have the database perform a join using Foreign keys. I cannot find joins, foreign keys, or any of the tags that Hibernate would use for that in the documentation. Is the process simply to join in Java?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to be certain is to measure it, however, much of the time of receiving the data from a SQL query is transferring the data of the network.

SQL Engines, of whatever type are highly optimised for selecting data in an efficient manner and most SQL servers have tools to help you optimise your queries in various ways.

Also, depending on your query, more locks might be held during a query that fetches everything, which could prevent other concurrent operations running efficiently. Again, most database engines (excluding SQLite) are designed for concurrent transactions, but work best when those transactions don't overlap on rows or data pages.

So, in general, I would expect a strategy of retrieve everything, followed by filter it to be less efficient than letting the SQL engine do what it is designed for.

Comment: Ok, you answered my first part, and I thank you for the information. What about how to do it using Spring Framework? How is a where or join done there?